# set progress bar value from other class android

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I have a progress bar in viewHolder class inside adapter class. I need to update that bar from another activity UpdateActivity when the method onPause that activity is implemented. I have tried using the interface but it does not update the progress bar, the bar remains as before with no error as well. Is there any way I can update the bar from given activity? Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

  public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
     implements MyCallBack {

        ProgressBar progressBar;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        }
    @Override
    public void updateMyText(int integer) {
        progressBar.setProgress(integer);
    }
        
    }

}

interface MyCallBack {
    public void updateMyText(int integer);
}
```

}

```
public class  UpdateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MyCallBack myCallBack;
int final_value;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        
        //

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

  
      /*  myCallBack = new MyCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void updateMyText(int integer) {
                progressBar.setProgress(100);
                
            }
        }; */

        final_value = position.getValue();  // final_value != null 
        progressBar.setProgress(final_value);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is your recyclerview for which you implemented the adapter?

I do not have a clear understanding of the task, what do you want to do here in the activity, it looks like it is a progress bar for loading a splash screen or something similar, then why do you need a recycler for this?

If the logic is that each item in the recyclerview (or another view) contains a progress bar, then in order to manage each specific progress bar you need:

1. Public method for set progress value in the MyViewHolder.
2. Reference to the concrete which view contains progressbar (for example, you can use some listener for this inside adapter constructor).

For interaction between activities you can use method startActivityForResult.

Comment: I tried using the public method for set progress value in MyViewHolder class with interface but could not do so. I have added above could you look and see how it could be solved?

Comment: You can't call methods from ViewHolder from activity or fragment., but it is possible to call methods from the adapter.

Comment: Also, you can mark ViewHolder class as "inner" then you will get access to fields of your adapter class if it will help. You may specify the position for the adapter, then the adapter will what item work with.

Comment: But how calling or accessing from adapter will solve the problem if you could explain with some code that would be really helpful.